# How to identify the nested element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a nested element possibly within `<svg>` that I can't seems to access

I tried using

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.login-fake-btn')
```

and

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'login-fake-btn')
```

and a few others.

HTML structure of nested svg:

```
<svg class="1">
<div id="2">
<div>
<div class="3">
<div class="4">
<li>
<button class="5" type="button" id="login-fake-btn">
...closing tags
```

Snapshot of HTML:

[image: HTML]

I have no success with xpath either.

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.login-fake-btn"}
```

How do I get to a nested svg using a css selector (or xpath, but I understand css to be better)?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `button#login-fake-btn` or `#login-fake-btn`?

Comment: . is for class, # is for id

Comment: Can you provide complete HTML of `svg` element which contains the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `<button>` element and it's out of the `<svg>` tag and possibly moving forward you'd invoke `click()` on it. Hence to locate the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.login-btn.btn-shadow#login-fake-btn[data-testid='login-fake-btn']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='login-btn btn-shadow' and @id='login-fake-btn'][@data-testid='login-fake-btn']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: I tried that and a couple of variations  https://i.imgur.com/l9AyPjZ.png with a timeoutexception error

Comment: @brad Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I get the following error
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: @brad Sounds great, so we identified the element correct. You never told us you would click :) that was my assumption. Okay, now without the text based HTML and the complete error trace log it's hard to guess anything more.